# How to update optional fields in a nested json array using Mongoose in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update optional fields of a farm that belong to a user. For example, if the user only wants to change the name from "Farm 1" to "Farm 99", a JSON will be sent like this:

```
{
    "name": "Farm 99"
}
```

this is an example of a user who has two farms:

```
     }
         "farms": [
            {
                "extension": {
                    "extension": 22,
                    "measure": "Hectares"
                },
                "animals": [],
                "outs": [],
                "plans": [],
                "_id": "5ae64b9f9564b42d31e5bb99",
                "name": "Farm 1",
                "createdAt": "2018-04-29T22:47:59.514Z",
                "updatedAt": "2018-04-29T22:47:59.514Z"
            },
            {
                "extension": {
                    "extension": 50,
                    "measure": "Hectares"
                },
                "animals": [],
                "outs": [],
                "plans": [],
                "_id": "5ae64ceeda4eb82e50502901",
                "name": "Farm 2",
                "updatedAt": "2018-04-29T22:53:34.467Z",
                "createdAt": "2018-04-29T22:53:34.467Z"
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5ae64b9f9564b42d31e5bb98",
        "name": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "username": "john99",
        "password": "123",
        "createdAt": "2018-04-29T22:47:59.514Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-29T22:53:34.467Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

and this is the code that I'm using for it:

```
exports.update = (req, res) => { // fix me
  User.update (
    { username: req.params.username, 'farms._id' : req.params.idFarm },
    { $set: {
      farms: req.body
    } }
  )
    .then(farm => {
      if (!farm) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: "Farm not found with ID  " + req.params.idFarm
        });
      }
      res.send(farm);

    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.kind === "ObjectId") {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: "Farm not Found with ID " + req.params.idFarm
        });
      }
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: "Error Updating Farm with ID " + req.params.idFarm
      });
    });
};
```

and this is the result:

```
"farms": [
            {
                "animals": [],
                "outs": [],
                "plans": [],
                "_id": "5ae659c55dacc836066102f3",
                "name": "Farm 99"
            }
        ],
```

As you can see, when you try to update all the farms are deleted and only the one that you try to update but with incomplete fields is left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are updating the entire array, only the updated object appears in the array. You need to use the [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator together with the [$ positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator.

```
User.update (
{ username: req.params.username, 'farms._id' : req.params.idFarm },
{ $set: { "farms.$.name": req.body.name } } )
```

That should only replace only the affected object in the array and update only the name attribute.

If you would like to replace the entire object, try this:

```
User.update (
{ username: req.params.username, 'farms._id' : req.params.idFarm },
{ $set: { "farms.$": req.body } } )
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers